# Relationship between the __eq__ attribute and the equality operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators, equality

So the following built-in classes have a `__eq__` attribute, which (I assume) is why you can test their instances for equality:

```
>>> 1.2.__eq__( 1.2 )
True
>>> 1.2 == 1.2
True
>>> 'hello'.__eq__( 'hi' )
False
>>> 'hello' == 'hi'  
False
>>> [1,2].__eq__( [1,2] )
True
>>> [1,2] == [1,2]  
True
```

Then I was surprised to see that `int` objects don't have `__eq__`, but we can still compare them:

```
>>> hasattr( 1, '__eq__' )
False
>>> 1 == 2 
False
```

What's going on? Did I misunderstand the relationship between `__eq__` and the equality operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` objects have a [`__cmp__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) instead:

> Called by comparison operations if rich comparison (see above) is not defined.

where *rich comparison* includes `__eq__`.

Demo:

```
>>> (1).__cmp__(2)
-1
>>> (1).__cmp__(1)
0
>>> (1).__cmp__(0)
1
```

When `__cmp__` returns `0` the two values are equal.

Python 3 does away with `cmp()` comparisons and the associated special methods; in Python 3 `int` *does* have an `__eq__` method:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> (1).__eq__(1)
True
```

In addition, Python 3 `int` objects provide the other [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) too; `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`, all methods missing on the Python 2 version.

Python started out with *just* `__cmp__`, rich comparisons support was only added in Python 2.1 (see [PEP 207](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/)), and integers were not converted over until Python 3. There is little point in keeping two systems of comparison around, hence the ditching of the less expressive form.

Comment: _in Python 3 int does have a `__cmp__` method:_ - I think you've meant _does have a `__eq__` method_